# Android get emulator given name of device, or vice versa

Tags: android-emulator, adb

Currently when I run `adb devices` it gives me a list of devices that looks something like:

```
emulator-5554    device
emulator-5556    device
```

My goal is to find a command that I can run in the shell that takes a device name as a parameter, e.g. `Nexus7` and returns the corresponding device serial, e.g. `emulator-5554`.  If that isn't possible, I want to be able to have a function that takes `emulator-5554` as the parameter and returns `Nexus7` (the opposite direction of the former function) which I will then loop over all the devices in `adb devices` and figure out which one matches `Nexus7`.

**UPDATE**

I found a workaround solution which was to specify the port number when I launch the avd and then I know which emulator maps to which avd name, but ideally I would still like to know the answer here.

Comment: emulator -list-avds

Answer (score 9):

It's possible with telnet to emulator. It's not a single command unfortunately, but in general it's possible to automate it with shell. Here is the basic idea:

1. Find emulator's port number (5554):

   ```
   $ adb devices
   List of devices attached
   emulator-5554   device
   ```
2. Telnet to emulator:

   ```
   $ telnet localhost 5554
   Trying 127.0.0.1...
   Connected to localhost.
   ...
   OK
   avd name
   Nexus7
   ```

**Nexus7** is the avd name.

See also this answer to find how to make telnetting in one line:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5608081

Answer (score 0):

- get the list of PIDs for all running emulator processes
- parse their cmdlines, collect avd names
- check tcp ports opened by those processes
- match open ports against `adb devices` output